# MySQL on Docker “Connection Refused” despite being able to connect via MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, docker

I’m trying to set up a local dev environment for WordPress with MySQL.

After starting the container, the WordPress element works fine and is accessible.

But MySQL throws `connection refused` despite being able to connect using the same database details in MySQL Workbench.

I have tried changing the host from `dB:3306` to `0.0.0.0:3306` but to no avail.

Using Docker for Mac OS.

Dockerfile:

```
---

  version: '3.3'

  services:
    db:
      image: mysql:5.7.30
      volumes:
        - ./database:/var/lib/mysql
        - ./mysqldumps/production-backup.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/production.sql
        - ./init/migrate.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/migrate.sh
      restart: unless-stopped
      networks:
       - wp
      ports: 
        - '3306:3306'
      environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: $db_root_password
        MYSQL_DATABASE: $db_name
        MYSQL_USER: $db_user
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: $db_password
        WORDPRESS_TABLE_PREFIX: $db_table_prefix
        PRODUCTION_URL: $production_url     

    wordpress:
       depends_on:
         - db
       image: wordpress:latest
       volumes:
         - ./wordpress/wp-content:/var/www/html/wp-content
         - ./init/prep.sh:/usr/local/bin/prep.sh
       ports:
         - '80:80'
       restart: unless-stopped
       networks:
        - wp
       environment:
         WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: $db_host
         WORDPRESS_DB_USER: "root"
         WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: "password"
         WORDPRESS_TABLE_PREFIX: $db_table_prefix
         WORDPRESS_DEBUG: $wp_debug_mode
         DISABLED_PLUGINS: $wp_plugins_to_disable

  networks:
    wp:

  volumes:
    database:
```

Does anybody have any ideas what’s going on here?

Comment: you have to publish/expose your db port to your local machine, but the question as its written now we can't help much, you should add your Dockerfiles/docker-compose files code to the question, that would help addressing your issue.

Comment: @Ma'mounothman - added my Dockerfile. I'm not sure if exposing ports is the issue; I can connect perfectly fine using MySQL Workbench, and from my understanding, you don't need to expose ports from Mac OS when using the Docker client.

Comment: do you have the environment variables setup correctly? I suggest that you first try out to hardcode the values and if it worked then it is environment variables issue.

Comment: @Ma'mounothman - I've just done that, these are the errors I get back:

wordpress_1  | MySQL "CREATE DATABASE" Error: Can't create database 'wordpress' (errno: -632623824)
wordpress_1  | 
wordpress_1  | WARNING: unable to establish a database connection to 'db:3306'
wordpress_1  |   continuing anyways (which might have unexpected results)